# DocumentDB Java SDK behind a proxy

Tags: java, proxy, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to create a simple web application from the [todo tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/documentation/articles/documentdb-java-application/).
As I'm behind a corporate proxy, I used the following common java system properties :

```
 -Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy Dhttp.proxyPort=3128
 -Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128
```

I also try the following parameter:

```
 -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
```

I still have a client exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Http client execution failed.
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.GatewayProxy.performPostRequest(GatewayProxy.java:350)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.GatewayProxy.doSQLQuery(GatewayProxy.java:135)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.doQuery(DocumentClient.java:2013)
(...)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:625)
```

I would like to know if the [azure documentdb sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java) enable this proxy settings ? Maybe there is another way to set https proxy for this SDK ?

Comment: related pull request: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java/pull/22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [pull request](http://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java/pull/22) merge, if you want to use a proxy you need to get a release version greater than 1.0.1.

As the release is not available at this moment, you could build github source and use the sdk snapshot version.

Then you just need to setup your proxy through configuration:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy Dhttp.proxyPort=3128
-Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128
```

Comment: I'm using 1.11, it still does not respect the -Dhttps.proxyHost argument.

Comment: Did you set https.proxyPort too ? If yes.. no more idea.

Comment: It ignores the command line argument.  I ended up getting it to work with
connectionPolicy.setProxy(new HttpHost(InetAddress.getByName("proxy.company.com"), 12345));

Comment: How to set proxy with username and password ?

Comment: I tried that but its not working. Only difference I have in my code is that, I am setting arguments programmatically like `System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "10.1.1.253")`. It should work, right ?